# $a+b+c=3$ prove: $\frac{a^2}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+ac+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+ba+a^2}+6\ge 2abc+\frac{5}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge7$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0: a+b+c=3.$ Prove that: $$\frac{a^2}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+ac+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+ba+a^2}+6\ge 2abc+\frac{5}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)\ge7$$

For right inequality I used Schur inequality: $r\ge\frac{4q-9}{3}$ and We need to prove: $\frac{5}{3}(9-2q)+2\frac{4q-9}{3}\ge7 \iff q\leq 3$ which is obviously true.

.Also I found that by C-S: $$\frac{a^2}{b^2+bc+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2+ac+a^2}+\frac{c^2}{b^2+ba+a^2}\ge\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+abc(a+b+c)}\ge\frac{3(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)}{2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2)+abc(a+b+c)}\ge 1$$ This weaker one true since: $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\ge abc(a+b+c)$

For the left inequality, I  still can not find a approach for it. Hope to see more idea to solve problem. Thanks!